# Conflicting Licenses: Can binary be released even though one library is missing?

Tags: license-compatibility, gpl-3, mpl

I have developed a C++ project which is meant to be used as a plugin in a third party software. The project includes three libraries:

A: The development kit of the third party software mentioned above

B: A GPL'd library (version 3)

C: An MPL'd library (verison 2.0)

The license of A allows me to distribute binaries but not the library source itself. Is it allowed to share all codes, including the part written by me but excluding the library A, as well as the binaries under GPLv3? According to my research, B & C do not conflict with each other since MPL2.0 can be embedded in GPLv3 but recipients would not be able to compile the project and obtain the binaries themselves because of the missing library A.

Thanks for helping me out here!

Comment: Is the third party software open source, i.e. can you distribute the source code of the main program (i.e. the program that you are going to use the plug-ins with)?

Comment: See also: [GPL FAQ - When is a program and its plug-ins considered a single combined program?](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLPlugins)

Comment: The main program is free but not open source (you can request it at the vendor's webpage).

Comment: The answer will depend on how the plug-in system works. If the plug-in system effectively combines the GPL program into the closed source one (so that they behave as one program afterwards), then that is not allowed by the GPL; you would have to distribute the source code of the closed source program in order to comply, but you can't do that because it's closed source. See the GPL FAQ item above for more information.

Comment: Are you sure the library is GPL and not LGPL?

Comment: "If the main program dynamically links plug-ins, but the communication between them is limited to invoking the ‘main’ function of the plug-in with some options and waiting for it to return, that is a borderline case." I think this pretty much applies except that there are more than one function being called and waited for to return. One of the libraries is FFTW3 and if I interpreted their page correctly it's GPL and not LGPL.

Comment: The main point I'm struggling with is really the fact that without library A nobody could recompile the binaries which I would like to offer especially to the people who just want to use the plugin without modifications. All the knowledge (numerical data treatment / analysis strategies) would be accessible and purely the vendor's namespace used for memory access is missing in source form.

Comment: For FFTW3 this is answered in the [FAQ](http://www.fftw.org/faq/section1.html#nonfree): "The non-free licenses are for companies that wish to use FFTW in their products but are unwilling to release their software under the GPL (which would require them to release source code and allow free redistribution). ... Contact us for more details."

Comment: Yeah, but I'm using the free version of FFTW3.

Comment: The question is, does GPL generally demand for ALL source codes needed to compile a binary or is it exceptionally permitted to leave gaps because of a missing license to publish a library soruce?

Comment: Basically, if you release something under the GPL or including something with a GPL component, you must agree to include all source code to rebuild it. If you cannot do that (e.g. because some third party source code is not available), then you canot use that GPL component. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I was afraid that's the answer but it matches my interpretation of the license. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> Recipients would not be able to compile the project and obtain the binaries themselves because of the missing library A.

If you are distributing and including GPL code in your source code distribution (which you are, according to your comments), then to fulfill the GPL requirements you must distribute all source code. If a certain part of the source code (e.g. library A) is not available, then you cannot distribute that GPL component while also fulfilling its requirements. This is what is meant when we say a license is "incompatible" -- it means you tried to fulfill all the requirements (e.g. license A says you cannot distribute its source code, and license B says you *must* distribute *all* source code), but failed to do so.

A possible exception would be so-called "system libraries" or components, which are described in the following paragraph of the GPL v2:

> The source code for a work means the preferred form of the work for making modifications to it. For an executable work, complete source code means **all the source code for all modules it contains**, plus any associated interface definition files, plus the scripts used to control compilation and installation of the executable. However, as a special exception, **the source code distributed need not include anything that is normally distributed (in either source or binary form) with the major components (compiler, kernel, and so on) of the operating system on which the executable runs**, unless that component itself accompanies the executable.

The above quotation (emphasis added) is from the [GPLv2](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html), but similar language ("System Libraries") is in the [GPLv3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html) as well.

Based on this, if you were developing, say, a Windows application, you would need not include, for example, the source code to the Windows modules that are normally distributed with the operating system, compiler, kernel, or other major components of the Windows operating system.

However, seeing as you intend to distribute the executable version of library A along with your program, and seeing as the library A does not qualify as "a major component of the compiler, kernel, and so on, of the operating system on which the executable runs," I would say that this this exception does not apply in your case. So you will need to be able to distribute its source code in order to comply with the GPL.

Based on your comments, you are using the FFTW library, which is specifically licensed under the GPL along with a dual-licensing offer. See the [FFTW FAQ](http://www.fftw.org/faq/section1.html#nonfree). It is common to license something under a GPL license as well as a non-GPL license for the use case you describe (for producing non-free software). In this case your only recourse is to ask the author for an alternative (non-GPL) license, or to remove dependence on the library A, which seems to be what is mainly preventing you from distributing all the source code and thus complying with the GPL.